# Problem at reading and storing binary GPS data on SD Card

Tags: c++, parsing, binary-data

As Hardware, I'm using an Arduino Due and a GPS Receiver from u-Blox (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15005) for my project. I basically want to retrieve a certain message (UBX-RXM-RAWX) via UART. As I will parse this message in post-processing, it would be fine to just read all binary data and store it directly onto an SD card. Unfortunately, not being very experienced in C++, I'm having troubles storing binary data into any file.

I see I'm missing some general knowledge there, and so I wanted to ask if you could help me out? My code is attached as well or can be found on github: https://github.com/dariopa/GPS-Logging-Station/blob/master/GPS%20Station/_UBX_GPS_StoreBinaryMessage_RAWX_DUE/_UBX_GPS_StoreBinaryMessage_RAWX_DUE.ino

Thanks for any help!

```
// RETRIEVE RAWX MESSAGE FOR RINEX GENERATION.

// Microcontroller: Arduino DUE
// GPS Receiver: NEO-M8P-2 (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15005)

#include <SD.h>

File binaryFile;
const int CS = 10; // ChipSelect

const char UBLOX_INIT[] PROGMEM = {
  // Disable NMEA
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x24, // GxGGA off
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x2B, // GxGLL off
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x32, // GxGSA off
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x39, // GxGSV off
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x40, // GxRMC off
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x47, // GxVTG off

  // Disable UBX
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x02, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x26, 0x46, // RXM-RAWX off

  // Enable UBX
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x02, 0x15, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27, 0x4B, // RXM-RAWX on

  // Rate
  0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x39, //(1Hz)
  // 0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0xD0, 0x07, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xED, 0xBD, // (0.5Hz)
  // 0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x0B, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xD9, 0x41, // (0.33Hz)

};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  delay(3000);
  // send configuration data in UBX protocol
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(UBLOX_INIT); i++) {
    Serial1.write( pgm_read_byte(UBLOX_INIT + i) );
    Serial.write( pgm_read_byte(UBLOX_INIT + i) );
    delay(10); // simulating a 38400baud pace (or less), otherwise commands are not accepted by the device.
  }

  // SD CARD
  // Initialize SD Card
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin(CS)) {
    Serial.println("Initialization of SD card failed - Freeze!");
    while (1) {}
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Initialization done.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    // read from port serial, send to port Serial:
    char Coord[300] = {Serial1.read()};
    Serial.write(Coord);
    binaryFile = SD.open("Data.bin", FILE_WRITE);
    if (binaryFile) {
      binaryFile.println(Coord);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't specify what sort of "troubles" you're having with storing the binary data.  At a guess, you might need to add a `FILE_BINARY` flag to your `SD.open` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char Coord[300] = {Serial1.read()};
```

This initialized `Coord[0]` to the return of `Serial1.read()`. The rest of 299 member of `Coord` array are initialized with zero.

If `Serial1.read()` returns an integer `int`. If it's `-1` than read was not succcessfull. Otherwise it's one valid character.

You want to read one character at a time and store it:

```
void setup() {
    ...

    // is there a point in opening the binaryFile each loop!?
    binaryFile = SD.open("Data.bin", FILE_WRITE);
    if (!binaryFile) { 
         // handle errror
         assert(0);
     }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int ci = Serial1.read();
    if (ci == -1) {
         // handle errpr
         return;
    }
    char c = ci;
    Serial.write(c);
    binaryFile.write(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented your inputs (https://github.com/dariopa/GPS-Logging-Station/blob/master/GPS%20Station/_UBX_GPS_StoreBinaryMessage_RAWX_DUE/_UBX_GPS_StoreBinaryMessage_RAWX_DUE.ino).
Regarding "is there a point in opening the binaryFile each loop?" The reason is that the data won't be written on the SD if it isn't opened in the loop() function. Furthermore, it requires a `binaryFile.close()` at the end (forgot in the old code). It works for now, but it would be better to store the data first in a buffer and then write the whole buffer into the SD card. Can I ask again for hints?

Comment: `File::close()` just calls [`File::flush()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileFlush), call it in the `loop()` then. If you want a buffer, just implement a global  `char array[128];` with `size_t arraypos;` and each character `array[arraypos++] = c;`. Flush + write (in that order) every n characters to the file.  Or you can find a vector library from online sites.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, it works like a charm now. Really helpful inputs!